C++ what's the best way to concatenate values into a char pointer
I'm new to C/C++ and I'm working on some old code that requires a char pointer. Is this code below the best approach for concatenating several values into a char pointer? TIA
    char buffer[SIZE];

    sprintf(buffer, "INSERT INTO IDTBL(ID1, ID2, ID3) VALUES (%u, %u, %u);", id1, id2, id3);

    char *sql = (char*) buffer;


best is to not confuse arrays with pointers. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. buffer is an array, it is not a pointer. buffer does decay to a pointer to its first element when eg passed to a function.

why is buffer not a std::string ?

Side note: Arrays decay into pointers, so the cast is unnecessary and probably detrimental because it can hide mistakes that the compiler could otherwise catch. In C++ a C-style cast like (char*) is the Word of God. The compiler stops thinking and does exactly what you tell it to do no matter how bad an idea that might prove to be. When you see a cast like that in C++ code, stop and look closely for the bug. Might not be one, but I've found enough over the years that I've almost certainly come out ahead in time spent.

@Michael Chourdakis sprint_s is not portable, snprintf is.

Your way is how it is done in C. It will be fine if you increase the buffer size to fit the largest unsigned for id1 etc. There are several C++-specific ways of doing it where you do not need to count characters manually.

I'm new to C/C++... C is a programming language.  C++ is a programming language.  C/C++ is a programming language I'm working on, which is derived from OCaml.  How did you get ahold of my C/C++ programming language, since I haven't released it yet?

@MichaelChourdakis Nor is sprintf_s any more "secure"

But enough of the nagging: Here's the tool you should most likely be using.

A bit out of topic, but generally, you should avoid formatting strings to generate SQL statements. This can be very dangerous, read about SQL Injection. True, with integers, there is basically no risk, but if you had strings, you would be pwned. Use prepared statements instead! And there they are typically much faster (at least with SQLite).

Thanks for all the comments. I'll see about moving the old code into a c++ string... but in the end I still need the char pointer so I'll do a c_str on it.

@prapin thanks for the tip... i'm migrating the code to use sqlite3

@user1337497 sqlite3 is a Python/PHP library. The core SQLite library supports prepared statements, you should use them.

The best approach would be to make a parameterized database call and pass these integers as parameters .
If you really must build the entire raw SQL string then your approach is okay, but it's important to protect against buffer overflow.  You may also want to check that the call was not truncated by running out of buffer, which could lead to erroneous behaviour in general :
int result = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "INSERT INTO IDTBL(ID1, ID2, ID3) VALUES (%u, %u, %u);", id1, id2, id3);
if ( result >= sizeof buffer )
    // ...abort or something

Also check that you do not deallocate buffer before the database call has completed .

I would recommend Creating and manipulating your text in the form of a  std::string, then only interpreting it as a char* at the last possible moment.
std::string buffer;
const char *sql = buffer.c_str();

You can build your string using a std::stringstream if you wish.
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "your text here" << id1<< std::endl;
std::string buffer = ss.str();
const char *sql = buffer.c_str();

